# Is there a fundamental theorem of calculus of variations?

Tags: functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations

In calculus of variations, we have the [functional derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative) (or, a variational derivative), and, naturally, a [functional integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_integration). However, I couldn't find anywhere the "fundamental theorem of functional calculus", connecting derivatives and integrals, analogous to the [fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus).

Does there exists a "fundamental theorem of calculus of variations"? Is there a connection between integral and derivatives in functionals?

Comment: You might want to check the Wikipedia thread for the fundamental lemma of the calculus of variations.

Comment: @CheeHan Hello. Well, I did, before asking this. But, despite its name, the lemma seems to not be a connection between integral and derivatives.

Comment: Just adding a link to [the fundamental lemma of calculus of variations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_lemma_of_calculus_of_variations).

Comment: Functional derivative corresponds to the gradient in multidimensional analysis, while functional integration corresponds to a volume integral. These are not inverses like in one dimension.